# Java Thread: Run method does not read Instance methods

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Battle extends Thread{
private Object instructor1;
private Object instructor2;


public Battle(Object instructor1, Object instructor2){
this.instructor1 = (Instructor)instructor1;
this.instructor2 = (Instructor)instructor2;
}

public void run(){



     System.out.print(instructor1.getCurrentHP());//DOES NOT WORK
  //}

}

public static void main(String[] args){
  Instructor instructor1 = new Instructor("Big Omar Latif", 999, 145, 180, 4000);
  Instructor instructor2 = new Instructor("Small Ali Raza", 400, 185, 230, 1200);
  Battle x = new Battle(instructor1, instructor2);

  System.out.print(instructor1.getCurrentHP()); //THIS WORKS

  x.start();

}


}
```

So i have a class where i have defined method,   .getCurrentHP() of the instructor when i print it in the main function, it works. But when i print it in the run method, it says symbol not found. whys that? how can i call my method?

Comment: The type of `instructor1` is `Object`, which doesn't have a `getCurrentHP()` method.

Comment: Your variables are of type `Object`. If you want to call  `Instructor` methods, use variables of type `Instructor`

Comment: Could you show me what you mean

Comment: To start with, "private Object instructor1" should be "private Instructor instructor1", and "public Battle(Object instructor1, Object instructor2)" should be "public Battle(Instructor 
instructor1, Instructor instructor2)"

Comment: It is not directly related to your problem, but extending `Thread` is something that you shouldn't normally do. Implement `Runnable` and pass the instance to a normal `Thread` (or an executor service) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The getCurrentHP() method works for objects of type Instructor. So you need to change  instructor1 & instructor2 from object to Instructor as shown below

```
public class Battle extends Thread{
 private Instructor instructor1;
 private Instructor instructor2;


public Battle(Instructor instructor1, Instructor instructor2){
 this.instructor1 = instructor1;
 this.instructor2 = instructor2;
}
```